# Issue centering images in WInForms App

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am having trouble with making my game centered and also a bit bigger on the screen when I go into full screen mode.
Is there any property or code that helps me?

Here's what it looks like right now:

[image]

All of my elements go to the left when they are on a little screen (800x600) (the normal screen the game is played on), the ones that seem to be on the right, go to the center and a bit off of that and the ones on the left seem to be almost centered.

Comment: Depends a bit on which controls you have used: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwinforms%5D+scaling. To be 100% sure : are you using WinForms, WPF or something else?

Comment: I am using Windows Forms App.

Comment: Can you explain how those controls sit on your form. Are they in any container/panel, like TableLayout or FlowLayout, maybe even usercontrols? It helps if we have an [mcve] that mimics what you have.

Comment: Can you please include the code you use to try and center it?  That may help pinpoint your issue

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it. I just turned the Property Anchor to None and that fixed it. Thank you all for helping though. :)

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Forms.Screen` contains properties that may be helpful.

The following code will get you the dimensions of the primary screen:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen _primaryScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen;
double _screenWidth = _primaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
double _screenHeight = _primaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

You can use calculated offsets/scales based on the size of the display.